# Move the mysql result from begin to the end

Tags: mysql

The 'start_date' field is of type 'date' in my table looks like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `exhibition` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `intro` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `logo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,  

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What I tried to achieve was say, today is Feb 18th, and the result of the query to list all records sort by start_date ascending is as below:

```
record id 1 (start_date: Jan 3rd)
record id 2 (start_date: Feb 1st)
record id 3 (start_date: Feb 19th)
record id 4 (start_date: Mar 5th)
```

how do I make the query so it lists the records (that is greater than today) by sorting the start_date descending and also moves the furthest records that past today to the end and stack up like below:

```
record id 3 (start_date: Feb 19th)
record id 4 (start_date: Mar 5th)   
                                 <---- Feb 18th (today)
record id 1 (start_date: Jan 3rd) (46 days past today)
record id 2 (start_date: Feb 1st) (17 days past today)
```

I use php and please let me know if I should use php to achieve this is mysql can't. If so how do I do it with php?

Comment: It's unclear to me how your table look like. Try that http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to make your table. (Or use `create` and `insert` statements)

Comment: I've updated, let me know if it's still unclear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  split the query up into 2 pieces - one containing all days past and one all days prior today - and add an extra column that imposes an artificial sort order for days before and after today. `UNION` it back up and sort first by the new column and then by the date like so:

```
SELECT id, start_date, 1 AS extraOrderColumn
FROM exhibition
WHERE start_date >= NOW()
UNION ALL
SELECT id, start_date, 2 AS extraOrderColumn
FROM exhibition
WHERE start_date < NOW()

ORDER BY extraOrderColumn ASC, start_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT `id`, `start_date`
FROM `exhibition`
WHERE `start_date` >= NOW()
ORDER BY `start_date` desc 
UNION ALL
SELECT `id`, `start_date`
FROM `exhibition`
WHERE `start_date` < NOW()
ORDER BY `start_date` asc;
```

Or if you want two distinct queries:

```
//Greater than today
SELECT `id`, `start_date`
FROM `exhibition`
WHERE `start_date` >= NOW()
ORDER BY `start_date` desc;

//PAST TODAY
SELECT `id`, `start_date`
FROM `exhibition`
WHERE `start_date` < NOW()
ORDER BY `start_date` asc;
```

Comment: AFAIK `UNION ALL` is not guaranteed to preserve the order. It might by chance give you the result order you want, but I would not recommend doing that. An update to the server could break that.

Comment: Yes, it does not preserve the order.